# Drill Down report Hyperlink shows "Birt Report Viewer" title

Tags: birt

I have a created a drill down birt report (i.e. a summary report and then a detail report). In my jsp I am using the birt reports tag library to show the reports in a report viewer. In these tags I've set showTitle="false". In the summary report this options works and the title does not show.

But when I click on my drill down link, the detail report shows a title of "Birt Report Viewer" appears. I guess that is a default title and there is a property or parameter in the hyperlink specification that I need to set which I am missing in order to hide that default title.

Can anyone help me with this please.

thanks

Comment: are you passing showTitle="false" for your drill down detail report

Comment: thanks for your tip. After I read it I tried something and it worked. I will add it to the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your top Sundar. After reading it I tried to pass through __showtitle=false in the report parameter screen and it worked. The title no longer displays after hitting the drill through link.

Before this I was unaware of the __notation. I guess that notation is reserved for special birt paramters.